# How do I implement a WCF Data Service context using async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm experimenting with [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx) (not to be confused with plain-old WCF), and I'd like to make my server methods asynchronous.  The amount of reflection used by the framework to connect endpoint methods to data context operations is hiding too much for me, and I can't find a way to make the service endpoint method asynchronous.

For instance, consider the following context that returns an `IQueryable<Customer>`.

```
public class StaticCustomerContext
{
    public IQueryable<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            IQueryable<Customer> customers = new[]
            {
                new Customer { CustomerID = 100, Name = "Domino's Pizza" },
                new Customer { CustomerID = 200, Name = "Sony" },
                new Customer { CustomerID = 300, Name = "Target" },
                new Customer { CustomerID = 400, Name = "Microsoft Corporation" }
            }.AsQueryable();

            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

The service entry point is straightforward:

```
public class MyWcfDataService : DataService<StaticCustomerContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
}
```

Now, how do I make the implementation of retrieving the Customers feed asynchronous?  If I change the `Customers` property on the context to return an instance of `Task<IQueryable<Customer>>`, then I get an exception in the `InitializeServiceMethod` stating that `Customers` cannot be found.

Is there a way to customize the service entry points to process `Task<IQueryable<T>>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: You are showing the service code and trying to make it asynchronous. Instead of you should try change client (caller) side. Also as this question relatively old - please tell if you found a solution. Place it here if yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think server-side async methods are supported in WCF Data Services.  Note that I would like to make the server methods asynchronous as I don't want to block server threads when it communicates with a database.  Making the client asynchronous is straightforward, but only allows better scale on the client side.